# Regular expression to validate text field format "WI-XXXX-XXXX"

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I want to validate the text box for WI text field using Jquery regular expression,
text format,
"WI-YYYY-XXXX"
In above format first "WI" followed by four digit Year(2000-2100), after that any four digit number range 1 to 9999.All separated by hyphen"-".

Example - 
          WI-2014-65
          WI-2015-786
          WI-2002-6752
          WI-2019-4

Please help me to validate this text format.

Comment: This has nothing to do with jQuery. It is just plain JavaScript

Comment: Stack Overflow really values if you've put some effort into solving your problems first; I advise you try tackling the problem yourself (perhaps by Googling for some regular expression tutorials) and then come back with more specific questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regexp would be:

```
/^WI-(?:20[0-9]{2}|2100)-[1-9][0-9]{0,3}$/
```

This regexp allows arbitrary number of `-nnn` after the year:

```
/^WI-(?:20[0-9]{2}|2100)(?:-\d+)+$/
```

Comment: How I can convert this expression for text like WI-2014-65-1, WI-2015-798-3, WI-2002-6752, WI-2019-4.

Comment: /^WI-2(?:100|0[0-9][0-9])-[0-9]{0,4}(-\d+)+$/;     I tried this but no Progress.

Comment: Salman, It will not allow values like WI-XXXX-XXX it only consider values like WI-XXXX-XXX-XX, It should allow both formats.

Comment: Did you check? `/^WI-(?:20[0-9]{2}|2100)(?:-\d+)+$/.test("WI-2000-123") // true` `/^WI-(?:20[0-9]{2}|2100)(?:-\d+)+$/.test("WI-2000-123-45") // true`

Comment: Thanks for your great efforts.Working fine :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this pattern `^WI-[0-9]{0,4}-[0-9]{0,4}$;`

Example:

```
var str = "WI-2014-6005"
str.match(/^WI-[0-9]{0,4}-[0-9]{0,4}$/);
```